# "with" for variables one of which might be None

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function which acquires 1 or 2 resources:

```
def my_function():
  res1 = None
  if some_cond:
    res1 = get_resouce1()

  res2 = get_resouce2()
  return res2, res1
```

When I'm doing this and `some_cond` is False, I get an exception:

```
  a2, a1 = my_function() 
  with a2, a1:
    # doing something.....


    # "a1" might be None here
    # thus the exception `AttributeError: __exit__` 
    # might be thrown when `a1` is None.

  print("helllllloooo")
```

How to fix that?

Comment: As mentioned by the error message ; I guess the value of `a1` is `None` due to which `with` is unable to call `__enter__` and `__exit__` magic functions

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, you've guessed right.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Quite new to Python here, but why don't you store your (res2,res1) return values in a tuple, and then go through it with a for loop?

Like :

```
foo = my_function()

for element in foo:
    doSomething(element)
```

And you could then check if a value is None.

(Sorry if this is not THE right way, trying to learn too... :))

EDIT :

Of course, I guess you can then use *with* on each element if it is not *None*

Comment: @Moinuddin Quadri : I understand my solution is wrong, and I was surprised seeing my proposition accepted by OP... But could anyone please tell me what's wrong with my noob approach instead of just downvoting ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Do not return `None`, use *Null Object Pattern* and return dummy context manager. It may be done quickly with [contextlib.contextmanager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) decorator.

```
import contextlib
@contextlib.contextmanager
def null_ctx_mgr():  # context manager that does nothing on enter and exit
    yield

def get_ctx_mgrs():
    # your function - returns context managers, never returns None
    return null_ctx_mgr(), null_ctx_mgr()

# actual usage
c1, c2 = get_ctx_mgrs()
with c1, c2:
    print(1)
```

Comment: By returning empty context manager instead of `None`? Are you expecting an answer which you can copy paste without any effort? That's not how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: it returns yield in your case. how can that be applied to my code?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager

Comment: I'd love to hear why answer was downvoted and how can it be improved.

Comment: @Saurabh this can be applied to your code by using `c1 = null_ctx_mgr()` instead of `c1 = None`; I don't think your accepted answer really does the trick according to the use-case you presented.

Comment: @Saurabh: You should be accepting this answer. The one you accepted currently is by no mean the right way to handle this. Answers on SO are for everyone and accepted answer is the shortcut to the right solution :)